# Kernel 5.3 does not support Elan9004 touch screen

Tags: release-hera, kernel, touchscreen

I've been having issues getting my touchscreen to work after the update to Linux Kernel `5.3.0-46-generic`. I am presently running Elementary OS 5.1.3 "Hera". System is up to date; just checked AppCenter.

I checked "dmesg" and I found this output:

```
[    5.487202] hid-generic 0018:04F3:299E.0004: item 0 1 0 8 parsing failed
[    5.487250] hid-generic: probe of 0018:04F3:299E.0004 failed with error -22
[    5.487852] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN9004:00: i2c_hid_get_input: IRQ triggered but there's no data
[    5.494961] hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:299E.0004: report is too long
[    5.494991] hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:299E.0004: item 0 1 0 8 parsing failed
[    5.495033] hid-multitouch: probe of 0018:04F3:299E.0004 failed with error -22
```

I did find a [similar issue reported on Manjaro Forums](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/elan-touch-screen-not-working-after-kernel-update/126146) and saw it is fixed as of Linux Kernel 5.4. I'd like help either upgrading my kernel to a newer version without using a PPA, or at least resolving this issue while staying on the kernel I am on. I'm afraid to upgrade the kernel as I do not want to cause issues with updates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to add a PPA to update a kernel. I advise you to delete those PPAs to avoid any issue in the future. You can use the command `sudo add-apt-repository --remove`.

To install a newer kernel go [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) and choose a version that you like. Then download from the amd64 section the corresponding files with the following names:

> - linux-headers*_all.deb
> - linux-headers*generic*.deb
> - linux-image*generic*.deb
> - linux-modules*generic*.deb

Lastly, install the kernel with `sudo apt install ./linux*.deb`. Make sure you open the terminal window in the correct folder.

Comment: I haven't installed any PPAs; your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This fixed my touch screen and stylus issue. Thank you very much!